# Applying the M-L estimate

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Show that $\lim_{R\to\infty}$$\oint_{|z|=R}$ $\frac{P(0)}{zP(z)} =0$. We are given that $P(z)$ is a non-constant polynomial in $z$, and that $P(z) \neq 0$.

Here is my attempt at the solution:

Since we have a circle centered at $0$ with radius R, the length of the circle we are integrating over is given by $2\pi$$R$, so we can choose our L for the estimate to be $2\pi$$R$. To find M, we can see that $\frac{|P(0)|}{|z||P(z)|}$ $\leq \frac{|P(0)|}{|R||P(R)|}$. So we pick $M=\frac{|P(0)|}{|R||P(R)|}$. Now by the ML estimate we have $\lim_{R\to\infty}$$\oint_{|z|=R}$ $\frac{P(0)}{zP(z)}$ $\leq$ $\lim_{R\to\infty}$$2\pi$$R$ $\frac{|P(0)|}{|R||P(R)|}$ = $\lim_{R\to\infty}$$\frac{|P(0)|}{P(R)}=0.$ As our integral is $\leq 0$ we have that the integral itself must be equal to $0$. Is this my stopping point or is this more that I have to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Note that $|\int_{|z|=R}\frac{P(0)}{zP(z)}\, dz|\leq \int_{|z|=R}\frac{|P(0)|}{|z||P(z)|}\, |dz|$. Using $z=Re^{i\theta}$ and parameterizing $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$, we have $dz=Rie^{i\theta}d\theta$ so $|dz|=Rd\theta$. Hence, an upper bound is
$$
|P(0)|\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{R|P(Re^{i\theta})|}R\,d\theta.
$$
The key is that as a function of $\theta,$ we have some $\theta_0$ such that $|P(Re^{i\theta})|\geq |P(Re^{i\theta_0})|$. This holds since polynomials are continuous. Hence, you should find an upper bound that converges to zero.

Comment: So this all makes sense, and I do see what I missed here, however, we are taking the limit of the left side as R-> $\infty$ so won't this correspond to the right side as well? Why can't we just take the limit of what we have now?

Comment: Also, I understand that you are doing |dz|, but is that necessary once we already know that the M-L estimate will work with what I did or is what I did just partial wrong with what you're saying?